# strange behaviour from *ngIf

Tags: html, angular

I am busy with a angular4 app where i'm trying to conditionally hide/show two div elements using *ngIf with very strange results.  I want to show the project form when newItem is false or null and show the item form when newItem is true.  The div containing the item form gets displayed as it should when newItem is true but the project form doesn't get removed from the dom for some reason...  I feel quite comfortable with angular and have been using it for a while but never came accross this issue?  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?  am I missing something very simple?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4 page-header">
            <h1>Quote generator</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4" *ngIf="!newItem">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <form [formGroup]="projectForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="calculateTotal(projectForm.value)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pName">Project Name</label>
                <input id="pName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter project name" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['name']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="markup">Markup(%)</label>
                <input id="markup" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter markup percentage" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['markup']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hCost">Hardware cost</label>
                <input id="hCost" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter hardware cost" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['hardwareCost']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lCost">Labour cost</label>
                <input id="lCost" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter labour cost" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['labourCost']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sCost">Sanding cost</label>
                <input id="sCost" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter sanding cost" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['sandingCost']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sdCost">Sundries cost</label>
                <input id="sdCost" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter Sundries cost" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['sundriesCost']">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-submit pull-right" [disabled]="!projectForm.valid || project.items.length < 1">Calculate</button> 
        </form>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4" *ngIf="newItem">
            <form [formGroup]="itemForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="addItem(itemForm.value)">              
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" Placeholder="Enter Item Name" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['name']">                              
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="height">Height</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="height" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item height" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['height']">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="length">Length</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="length" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item length" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['length']">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="width">Width</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="width" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item width" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['width']">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="qty">qty</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="qty" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item Quantity" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['qty']">              
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pcbm">Price/m<sup>3</sup></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item Price/cbm" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['priceM2']">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-submit" [disabled]="itemForm.valid">Add</button>
            </form>         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Item } from './models/item.model';
import { Project } from './models/project.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    itemsForm: FormGroup;
    projectForm: FormGroup;
    project: Project;
    item: Item;
    newItem: boolean = null;
    showProject: boolean = true;


    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.itemsForm = fb.group({
            'name': ['', Validators.required],
            'height': ['', Validators.required],
            'length': ['', Validators.required],
            'Width': ['', Validators.required],
            'qty': ['', Validators.required],
            'priceM3': ['', Validators.required],           
        });

        this.projectForm = fb.group({
            'name': ['', Validators.required],
            'markup': ['', Validators.required],
            'hardwareCost': ['', Validators.required],
            'labourCost': ['', Validators.required],
            'sandingCost': ['', Validators.required],
            'sundriesCost': ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    calculateTotal(project: any) {

    }

    addItem() {
        this.newItem = true;        
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

Comment: You wrote `itemsForm` in your component class while use `itemForm` within template. What do you expect? And why are you using `[formControl]` instead of `formControlName`?

Comment: @yurzui i've always used [formControl] is that wrong?  Thanks for spotting that typo however that still doesn't explain *ngIf's behaviour...

Comment: Your errors are connected with using reactive form not `ngIf`. Just look at console in webtools

Comment: Your mistake is in component.ts declare a variable itemsForm in formGroup but use name in html itemForm. and priceM3 key name is mismatched in html

Comment: @yurzui thanks please add that as the answer.  that resolved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with `ngIf`. I see a lot of misprints in your code

```
itemsForm => itemForm 
Width => width 
priceM3 => priceM2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4 page-header">
            <h1>Quote generator</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4" *ngIf="!newItem">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <form [formGroup]="projectForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="calculateTotal(projectForm.value)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pName">Project Name</label>
                <input id="pName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter project name" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['name']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="markup">Markup(%)</label>
                <input id="markup" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter markup percentage" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['markup']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hCost">Hardware cost</label>
                <input id="hCost" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter hardware cost" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['hardwareCost']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lCost">Labour cost</label>
                <input id="lCost" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter labour cost" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['labourCost']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sCost">Sanding cost</label>
                <input id="sCost" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter sanding cost" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['sandingCost']">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sdCost">Sundries cost</label>
                <input id="sdCost" class="form-control" placeHolder="Enter Sundries cost" type="text" [formControl]="projectForm.controls['sundriesCost']">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-submit pull-right" [disabled]="!projectForm.valid || project.items.length < 1">Calculate</button> 
        </form>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4" *ngIf="newItem">
            <form [formGroup]="itemForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="addItem(itemForm.value)">              
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" Placeholder="Enter Item Name" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['name']">                              
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="height">Height</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="height" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item height" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['height']">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="length">Length</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="length" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item length" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['length']">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="width">Width</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="width" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item width" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['width']">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="qty">qty</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="qty" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item Quantity" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['qty']">              
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pcbm">Price/m<sup>3</sup></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Enter item Price/cbm" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['priceM3']">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-submit" [disabled]="itemForm.valid">Add</button>
            </form>         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    itemForm: FormGroup;
    projectForm: FormGroup;
    project: any;
    item: any;
    newItem: boolean = false;
    showProject: boolean = true;


    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.itemForm = fb.group({
            'name': ['', Validators.required],
            'height': ['', Validators.required],
            'length': ['', Validators.required],
            'width': ['', Validators.required],
            'qty': ['', Validators.required],
            'priceM3': ['', Validators.required],
        });

        this.projectForm = fb.group({
            'name': ['', Validators.required],
            'markup': ['', Validators.required],
            'hardwareCost': ['', Validators.required],
            'labourCost': ['', Validators.required],
            'sandingCost': ['', Validators.required],
            'sundriesCost': ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    calculateTotal(project: any) {

    }

    addItem() {
        this.newItem = true;
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

Comment: what did you mean by my mistake is =>?

Comment: sorry. [formGroup]="itemForm" used in html file but you declare in ts file itemsForm and priceM3 is mismatch key name in itemForm